# Exporting Org in Landscape

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, org-table, pdf

I have an org document I'd like to export to PDF - with several wide tables columns in it - so much so that it makes sense to export the **whole** document in A4 landscape to keep the orientation consistent, and wrap the wide table cells where needed.

I'm sure this should be simple - but so far I've only managed to find a way of displaying the tables in landscape:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tabularx}
```

And then for each table:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :float sideways :environment tabularx :width \textwidth :align XllX
```

This works fine but there are 2 problems:

1) Only the tables are landscape - how can I set the whole document rather than just the tables?  I've taken a look at using:

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
```

And wrapping the whole document in:

```
\begin{landscape}

\end{landscape}
```

but results are unusable due to incorrect typesetting.  Is there some global org setting I can apply to the whole document?

2) Similarly, the ATTR_LATEX align setting to wrap the wide columns has to be set for each and every table.  As my tables are all of the same column order is there a way to globally set the table alignment for **every** table in the document?  My best guess so far is to write a macro to apply the align to each and every table - but I'm hoping there is an easier way I've missed?

I'm using emacs 25.2.1, org package 20171106, and pdflatex - pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)

Thanks

**Update**

I've taken a look a beamer mode - which nicely typesets stuff in landscape, but requires each bullet to be a single slide.  This isn't ideal because I want to produce a document where tables will flow over multiple pages if they are larger than one page.  In beamer mode it seems to truncate items larger than the slide.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about putting the following in the export options:

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [landscape]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[a4paper]{anysize}
```

Comment: Awesome! How would you set these options for a subtree?

Comment: I don't know. Put them directly after the top node of the subtree? Why?

Comment: I ask this in particular since I have one org file where each headline is a document, so I'd like to export one individual headline as a landscape pdf