# How to export a pdf in landscape rotation

Tags: pdf

Following example.org is expected to be exported in *landscape* though the generated pdf remains in *portrait*. What should I change?

```
** A3 PDF Landscape
   #+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}
   #+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[lscape]{geometry}
   #+ATTR_LATEX: :placement [H] :landscape
*** Flowchart landscape
    #+BEGIN_SRC mermaid :file myPicture1121.png
 graph LR
     john-->|calls|mary
    #+END_SRC
 #+RESULTS:
 [[file:myPicture1121.png]]
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LaTeX header is incorrect. You need to put all options for a package on one line, and the landscape option is `landscape` not `lscape`. It should read

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[a3paper,landscape]{geometry}
```

Your issue is thus entirely unrelated to Emacs and org mode.

Comment: The above solution does not work for me. But this one works: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36802/exporting-org-in-landsacpe

Comment: any other latex commands that make a document landscape should work as well, like the `#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [landscape]` you linked. Not sure why the `geometry` package doesn't work for you, though.